# opencv3 knearest object definition error

Tags: c++, knn, opencv3.0

I'm trying to implement a digi recognition program with c++ and opencv3, when i define a varible using KNearest i get this error:

```
main.cpp:19:18: error: variable or field 'RunSelfTest' declared void
 void RunSelfTest(KNearest& knn2);  
                  ^
main.cpp:19:18: error: 'KNearest' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:19:18: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from c:/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:48:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/ml.hpp:397:20: note:   'cv::ml::KNearest'
 class CV_EXPORTS_W KNearest : public StatModel
```

this is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"  
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp" 
#include <iostream>  
#include <stdio.h>  

using namespace cv;  
using namespace std;  

void RunSelfTest(KNearest& knn2);
void AnalyseImage(KNearest knearest);
```

i totally can't find where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `cv::ml::KNearest` but you're trying to refer to it as `KNearest` while `using namespace cv`.

But `KNearest` is also inside the `ml` namespace inside `cv::`. Try this:

```
ml::KNearest
```

(Or remove `using namespace …;` from your code, since it's [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3425536) anyway, and simply refer to it as `cv::ml::KNearest`.)

Comment: it worked for the first function but now i get cannot declare parameter 'knearest' to be of abstract type 'cv::ml::KNearest' for the second function

Comment: `KNearest` is an abstract class so it cannot be instantiated, and consequently cannot be passed by value. You have to pass it by reference.

Comment: oh ok... sorry but i'm new using c++ and opencv.... seems to be so hard for me to make working the knearest module of opencv